# Why does a .jasper pdf look different running it from java against ireport designer 5.6.0?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Design a report with ireport designer 5.6.0, but it looks different in ireport versus the one generated from a jsf application, as initial solution I added ireport fonts to the project and it solved the problem with the bold text, but for the font the sizes still being very different.

For example in a label from ireport it looks perfectly centered, but from Java the text does not fit, it looks much larger.

Comment: This is not related to JSF. JSF is mearly the 'transport' from server to client (and maybe not even that if you use a servlet)

Answer (score 0):

someone found this [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934218/jasper-reports-font-size-issue-exporting-to-pdf) post where something similar happened, taking into account my solution is: if from java the .jasper is used then the ireport designer must be 5.5.1 or earlier, if from java the .jrxml is used the jasperreports must be used -5.5.1.jar or earlier to compile, apparently the problem occurs when the report is compiled with 5.6 **